# Plotly Sankey diagram group label and color

Tags: python, plotly, sankey-diagram

I'm creating a sankey diagram using plotly and there is the built in method to use 'group' to combine nodes. However, when I use this the color of this node will be black and no label is showing. This is expected as the colors of the grouped nodes could vary. However, I don't see how I can set the color of the group. Same goes for the label. 
Is there a way to define this?

example code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot

value = [3,5,2,4,6]
source = [0,0,1,0,3]
target = [1,4,2,3,4]
color = ["blue","yellow","orange","orange","purple"]
label = ["A","B","C1","C2","D"]


data = dict(
    type='sankey',
    arrangement = 'freeform',
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(
        color = "black",
        width = 0.1
      ),
      groups = [[2,3]],
      label = label,
      color = color,
    ),
    link = dict(
        source = source,
        target = target,
        value = value,
      )
)

layout =  dict(
    title = "Sankey test",
    font = dict(
      size = 10
    )
)
f = go.FigureWidget(data=[data], layout=layout)
plot(f)
```

Which renders:
[image]

Comment: @Cvrisvdberge How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 4):

Since I'm getting the following error with your snippet:

> ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.sankey.Node: 'groups'

And since I don't know what versions you are running of plotly, python (and Jupyter Notebook?), I would simply suggest that you restructure your source data and do the C1 and C2 grouping into simply C before you build your plot. And keep in mind that [Links are assigned in the order they appear in dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301343/how-to-define-the-structure-of-a-sankey-diagram-using-a-dataframe) and that node colors are assigned in the order that the plot is built.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

# settings
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# Nodes & links
nodes = [['ID', 'Label', 'Color'],
        [0,'A','blue'],
        [1,'B','yellow'],
        [2,'C','orange'],
        [3,'D','purple'],
        ]

# links with your data
links = [['Source','Target','Value','Link Color'],
        [0,1,3,'rgba(200, 205, 206, 0.6)'],
        [0,2,5,'rgba(200, 205, 206, 0.6)'],
        [0,3,5,'rgba(200, 205, 206, 0.6)'],
        [1,2,6,'rgba(200, 205, 206, 0.6)'],
        [2,3,6,'rgba(200, 205, 206, 0.6)'],
        ]

# Retrieve headers and build dataframes
nodes_headers = nodes.pop(0)
links_headers = links.pop(0)
df_nodes = pd.DataFrame(nodes, columns = nodes_headers)
df_links = pd.DataFrame(links, columns = links_headers)

# Sankey plot setup
data_trace = dict(
    type='sankey',
    domain = dict(
      x =  [0,1],
      y =  [0,1]
    ),
    orientation = "h",
    valueformat = ".0f",
    node = dict(
      pad = 10,
    # thickness = 30,
      line = dict(
        color = "black",
        width = 0
      ),
      label =  df_nodes['Label'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
      color = df_nodes['Color']
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = df_links['Source'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
      target = df_links['Target'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
      value = df_links['Value'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
      color = df_links['Link Color'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
  )
)

layout = dict(
        title = "Sankey Test",
    height = 772,
    font = dict(
      size = 10),)

fig = dict(data=[data_trace], layout=layout)
iplot(fig, validate=False)
```

**My system info:**

```
The version of the notebook server is: 5.6.0
The server is running on this version of Python:
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is very old I found a solution for this issue as I faced the same challenge. Each group that you add using `groups` defines a new `node` (see [source code](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/f316a7a8a5b9d914664e6fbc9b851dd7ba98a6b0/src/traces/sankey/calc.js#L47C23-L47C23)). Hence, if you add another label and color to your `label` and `color` arrays everything should work.

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objs as go

value = [3,5,2,4,6]
source = [0,0,1,0,3]
target = [1,4,2,3,4]
color = ["blue","yellow","orange","orange","purple", "lime"]
label = ["A","B","C1","C2","D", "Group 1"]


data = dict(
    type='sankey',
    arrangement = 'freeform',
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(
        color = "black",
        width = 0.1
      ),
      groups = [[2,3]],
      label = label,
      color = color,
    ),
    link = dict(
        source = source,
        target = target,
        value = value,
      )
)

layout =  dict(
    title = "Sankey test",
    font = dict(
      size = 10
    )
)
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=[data], layout=layout)
pio.renderers.default = 'iframe'
# Display the plot
fig.show()
```

The result should look like the picture below.

[image: screenshot of the resulting diagram]