# How to add more space between title and Sankey Diagram?

Tags: python, plotly, sankey-diagram

I'm using python with plotly to create Sankey Diagram. this it the text for the title/subtitles & a picture of the problem (the title overlaps with the diagram). How can I create more space between the two? I've tried adding "height=#' to the layout but that changes the width of my Sankey Diagram instead.

```
line2="From time: "+str(time_from)+" to time: "+str(time_to)
line3="\nDATA 1:"+"{:.4f}".format(pue)
line4="\nDATA 2 :"+"{:.4f}".format(ere)

layout =  dict(
        title = 'TITLE HERE'+ '<br>' + '<span style="font-size: 12px;">'+line2+'</span>' + '<br>' + '<span style="font-size: 12px;">'+line3+'</span>' + '<br>' + '<span style="font-size: 12px;">'+line4+'</span>',
        

)
```

[image]
Also, my Sankey Diagram code set up is similar to the answer to this stack overflow question:
[Plotly Sankey diagram group label and color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862005/plotly-sankey-diagram-group-label-and-color)

Answer (score 4):

Using the code in the other question that you provided, and simply just adding this line into your code: `f.update_layout(margin=dict(t=200))` you can change something like this:

[image]

into this:
[image]

You can obviously try out different values to see what works best for you, but simply adding the `update_layout` to change the `margin` for the `top (t)` should do the job for you.