# Is it possible to add more white space between this title and plot?

Tags: python, plot, sankey-diagram

I'm using python with plotly to create a Sankey Diagram. I've attached an image below that shows how the subtitle text overlaps with the Sankey Diagram- which I don't want. Is it possible to create more white space between the two? I've tried adding "height=#' to the 'layout' part of the code but that just changes the width of my Sankey Diagram.

```
line2="From time: "+str(time_from)+" to time: "+str(time_to)
line3="\nDATA 1:"+"{:.4f}".format(pue)
line4="\nDATA 2 :"+"{:.4f}".format(ere)

layout =  dict(
        title = 'TITLE HERE'+ '<br>' + '<span style="font-size: 12px;">'+line2+'</span>' + '<br>' + '<span style="font-size: 12px;">'+line3+'</span>' + '<br>' + '<span style="font-size: 12px;">'+line4+'</span>',)
```

Also, my Sankey Diagram code set up is similar to the answer to this stack overflow question: [Plotly Sankey diagram group label and color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862005/plotly-sankey-diagram-group-label-and-color)

[image]

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but for me, usually appending multiple newlines to the title solves the problem quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried that already but didn't work :/

Comment: In that case, sorry, I've never used `plotly` in my life :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add more space between title and Sankey Diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008606/how-to-add-more-space-between-title-and-sankey-diagram)

Comment: Is this an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008606/how-to-add-more-space-between-title-and-sankey-diagram ?  Could you delete this one as the other has answers?  thanks.