# How to visualize word patterns?

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, pydot, altair

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
<client>: {
    <document>: [
        {'start': <datetime>,
         'end': <datetime>,
         'group': <string>}
    ]
 }
```

The list of dictionaries within a `<document>` is sorted by the `'start'` date, and a new entry cannot start before the one before it ends. I iterate over this data structure and I collect the values of `group` as time progresses into a new structure, e.g.:

```
<client>: {
    <document>: {'progression': <group_1>|<group_2>|...|<group_n>}
 }
```

where `<group_1>` corresponds to the value of `'group'` for the first dictionary in `<document>`, and so on. I want to visualize this progression of `groups` for all documents, so for example I know that I have 5,000 entries starting with "abc" (before the first pipe); out of those, 2,000 are followed by "def", so `"abc"|"def"`. Of those, 500 revert back to "abc": `"abc"|"def"|"abc"` and the remaining 1,500 are followed by "ghi": `"abc"|"def"|"ghi"`. The remaining 3,000 entries starting with "abc" follow some different progression pattern.

What I am trying to do is visualize this progression via something looking like a Sankey diagram, or an other appropriate tree-like structure, in which the top node would be "abc", then there would be a "thick" branch to the left corresponding to the different progression pattern, and a "thinner" branch to the right corresponding to the 2,000 "abc" cases followed by "def". Then "def" would be another node with similar branches, one leading to a new "abc" (for the `"abc"|"def"|"abc"` case) and one leading to "ghi" (for the `"abc"|"def"|"ghi"` case), preferably annotated with the count in each node as the "tree" thins down. I use a combination of Python `Counter` structures to retrieve the numbers for each potential progression, but I do not know how I can create a visualization programmatically.

My understanding is that it is probably a problem that can be addressed using dot language, and packages like `pydot` and/or `pygraphviz`, but I am not sure whether I am on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case Sankey diagrams will be the best choice. Let's suppose you are have `data` structure that stores your groups info from here: `'progression': <group_1>|<group_2>|...|<group_n>`. Then you can construct Sankey diagram like this:

```
data = [
    [1,2,3,1,4],
    [1,4,2],
    [1,2,5,3,5],
    [1,3],
    [1,4,5,1,4,3],
    [1,5,4,3],
    [1,2,5,1,3,4],
    [1,5],
    [1,2,1,1,5,2],
    [1,5,4,3],
    [1,1,2,3,4,1]
]

# Append _1, _2... indices to differ paths like 1-2-2-1 and 1-2-1-2
nodes = sorted(list(set(itertools.chain(*[[str(e) + '_' + str(i) for i, e in enumerate(l)] for l in data]))))
countered = defaultdict(int)
for line in data:
    for i in range(len(line) - 1):
        countered[(str(line[i]) + '_' + str(i), str(line[i+1]) + '_' + str(i+1))] += 1
links = [
    {'source': key[0], 'target': key[1], 'value': value}
    for key, value in countered.items()
]

links = {
    'source': [nodes.index(key[0]) for key, value in countered.items()],
    'target': [nodes.index(key[1]) for key, value in countered.items()],
    'value': [value for key, value in countered.items()]
}

data_trace = dict(
    type='sankey',
    domain = dict(
      x =  [0,1],
      y =  [0,1]
    ),
    orientation = "h",
    valueformat = ".0f",
    node = dict(
      pad = 10,
      thickness = 30,
      line = dict(
        color = "black",
        width = 0
      ),
      label =  nodes
    ),
    link = links
)

layout =  dict(
    title = "___",
    height = 772,
    font = dict(
      size = 10
    ),    
)

fig = dict(data=[data_trace], layout=layout)
iplot(fig, validate=True)
```

It will draw you a Sankey plot like this:

[image]

You can find more info about how Sankey in plotly works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55355445/11227781).

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, @vurmux. Starting from this code snippet, I managed to create a family of very complex Sankey diagrams doing what I want. The addition of the underscored 1,2, etc to account for progress in time was a game changer.